# How to pass and retrieve a realm result from a ListView in another Activity?

Tags: android, realm

I have a realm database object each with 4 properties. In the first activity I put a Listview to display only one of the property, i.e Event. On clicking any one of the displayed events,  I want to go to Activity 2 (details view)  which will display all of the other 3 properties associated with the clicked Event. How to I do this with intent and how do I retrieve all the properties to be displayed individually in Activity 2?

```
public class Events extends RealmObject {

    public String fileRef;
    public String event;
    public String venue;
    public String date;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " \n Events{" +
                "fileRef='" + fileRef + '\'' +
                ", parties='" + event + '\'' +
                ", \n court='" + venue + '\'' +
                ", courtAt='" + date + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getFileRef() {
        return fileRef;
    }

    public void setFileRef(String fileRef) {
        this.fileRef = fileRef;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setCourtAt(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

The code below is in the 1st Activity. All I got is to pass only one property i.e event. How do I get to pass and retrieve all the properties in Activity2?

```
public class AllEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_events);


        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);




        Realm realm;
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmResults<Events> results = realm.where(Events.class).findAll();

        ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Events events : results)

        {
            rows.add(Events.event);


        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rows);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedEvent = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Intent eventDetailIntent = new Intent(AllEventActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                eventDetailIntent.putExtra("event", selectedEvent);
                startActivity(eventDetailIntent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Below is the code in Activity2. I only managed to make the toast display the event.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String selectedEvent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_detail);

        selectedEvent = getIntent().getExtras().get("event").toString();
        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, selectedCase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Your answer is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gson library, you need to add an import inside your gradle file to use it

With Gson you can cast your Events to String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
intent.putExtra("event", gson.toJson(selectedEvent));
```

And you can get your object in your next activity with Gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Events yourEvent = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("event"), Events.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My app crashed when I click the selected item to go to the 2nd activity.

Comment: I think your code crash here getIntent().getExtras().get("event").toString(); the get method maybe return null and you try to call toString on null object

Comment: I may understand what you are saying incorrectly but I’ve made sure the property called upon has a value and not null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bundle,

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


private String selectedEvent;

Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_detail);


    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null){

        try {
            String selectedEvent = bundle.getString("event");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code:
I passes Event model 1st to 2nd activity

> Model Class

```
public class Events extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    public String fileRef;
    public String event;
    public String venue;
    public String date;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " \n Events{" +
                "fileRef='" + fileRef + '\'' +
                ", parties='" + event + '\'' +
                ", \n court='" + venue + '\'' +
                ", courtAt='" + date + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getFileRef() {
        return fileRef;
    }

    public void setFileRef(String fileRef) {
        this.fileRef = fileRef;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setCourtAt(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

> Liveview Click Event:

```
Intent eventDetailIntent = new Intent(AllEventActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        eventDetailIntent.putExtra("event", results.get(position)); // Selected postion item
        startActivity(eventDetailIntent);
```

> In your 2nd Activity, you can retrieve your passed model data.

```
 Events eventModel = ( Events) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("event");
```

So you will have your data in eventModel Object. Now you can get data from that model and set into your `TextViews`.

Like

```
textview1.setText(eventModel.getEvent())
textview2.setText(eventModel.getVenue())
textview3.setText(eventModel.getDate())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry for the  late response as I was away from my laptop for a few days. Is the model you pass to the Activity2 the whole model or just the one selected in activity 1?

Comment: I think the code for the intent has issues. Whenever I clicked the item in the listView to go to the 2nd Activity the app crashed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe something I did wrong in my code? How do I extract the passed data to set on different textviews?

Comment: The intent code may have a problem. Like I said before, the app crashed once I click on any one of the event in the Listview and won’t go to the 2nd Activity. In 2nd activity java  file however it seems the model was passed as I can get all the other properties as I wanted.  Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing the word “results” in the intent code was underlined automatically in my java class. Is it anything that I should take note of?

Comment: There is a suggestion by the compiler to “introduce local variable” for results.